# Reference counted Pub/Sub system

Tags: publish-subscribe, reference-counting

I am searching for a way to design my system that consists of multiple publishers, multiple channels and multiple subscribers, all of which can be uniquely identified easily.
I need to send messages in both directions, with as low as possible latency. However, if a subscriber dies, the messages he subscribed to should not be dropped, when it comes back online, it should receive all pending messages. Since I handle with very high numbers of messages (up to 1000 per second happens on a regular basis) while having a low-spec server, meaning keeping lists of all messages at all times is not an option.

I was considering if a reference count/list for messages is a viable option. When a message is published, it is initialized with a list of subscribers to that specific channel, when a subscriber receives the message, the subscriber is removed from the list. The message is removed if the list is empty.

Now, if a subscriber dies without unsubscribing, the messages will not be removed because the list of missing subscribers is not empty. When it comes back online, it will be able to receive the list of all pending messages, since it identifies with the same ID as the dead instance.

Perhaps it would be required to have messages/subscribers time out, for example if a subscriber has been inactive for 10 minutes, all list entries containing it are cleared.

Is that a good idea, have I forgotten problems that could arise with this system in particular? Is there any system that already does this? RabbitMQ and similar PubSub systems dont seem to have this - if not, I guess redis is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine managing reference count for the purposes of message lifecycles. This sounds reasonable in terms of message and memory management during normal Service operation. Of course, timeouts provide patch for references from dead services.

However in terms of health monitoring and service recovery issues this is quite another story.

The danger that I currently see here is state management. Imagine a service that is a stateful subscriber (i.e. has a State Machine)  that is driven from it initial state (I) to a certain state (S). Each message is being processed differently in different states. Now imagine that your service dies and gets restarted. Meanwhile some messages are stored and after the service is back online, they are dispatched to it. However the Service receives them in the wrong state (I instead of S) and acts unexpectedly.

Can you restore the service in the exact state it was when crashed? In practice, this is extremely difficult since even in the State Machine approach the service has side effects / communicates with global state(s) etc.

Bottomline, reference counting seems reasonable in terms of managing Messages, but mixing it with health monitoring results in lots of complexity issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The messages and are in fact stateless, therefore I dont see a problem with that. I have started implementing the system using redis, I will see if it works out the way I hope it does.